# Rounded Corners

Tags: php, javascript, rounded-corners

I am wondering whats the best way to programmatically make rounded corners for images. This can be either using PHP or javascript. An algorithm will also do for the same and I can code it with Image::Magick or GD.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823218/how-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css-or-javascript

Comment: Not exactly sure about the question, because it sounds so simple. What about drawing 4 circles http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagickdraw-circle.php and 2 rectangles? http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagickdraw-rectangle.php

Comment: Ups, there is even a function that draws rounded ractangles in imagemagick: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagickdraw-roundrectangle.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [curvy corners](http://www.curvycorners.net/demos/) or [nifty cube](http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html)

Comment: Curvy corners FTW! :D
Nifty corners can't always round in IE. I have tried it in the Drupal's primary menu but it doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`border-radius`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/#the-border-radius).

It is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5+, and Opera.

For the best possible browser support, you should prefix with `-webkit-` and `-moz-`:

```
.round {
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 

  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 12px; 

  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  border-radius: 12px; 
}
```

If you need a JavaScript solution for older browsers check out [jQuery Corner](https://github.com/malsup/corner).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what exactly you need. Do you want the corners to be transparent, or filled in some color? Which image format?

Here is some help for making rounded corners:
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=8401

Check it out, and if it does not help, update your question with the specific problem. Then we can probably help :-):

Answer (score 1):

use JavaScript to programatically get [round corners](http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner-demo.html)

OR

you can use mozilla and safaris browser extensions to get round corners using CSS but it will work only in Mozilla and Safari

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: That automatically make it a nonviable solution, seeing that 90+% users are still using the buggy crap that is IE

Comment: Make that 65.80% [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Present_to_1999] (or, in any case, something around that number). Also, IE8, hopefully starting to gain users, seems to be less loaded with problems.

Comment: This Comment is to : futureelite.

Dont contractdict yourself. If 90+% of people are using it, how come it could be buggy crap! I know IE has some defects but it is really getting better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the above mention tags with CSS, and for IE, use DDRoundies with some jquery code to make it work in IE. It is what I had to do to get it working. Good example of this is http://swiftmailer.org/ site. they make use of what I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Here are links for two **PHP** based solutions:

1. [Apply rounded corners to images](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2009/05/generate-images-with-round-corners-on.html) is a PHP script that embeds rounded corner on the image itself
2. [PHP rounded corner generator script](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2009/10/rounded-corner-graphics-generator.html) generates four corners that you can place over your image using CSS positioning -- or you can use them in your CSS/HTML layouts that require boxes with round corner.

Comment: thanks. solution 1 was exactly what i needed: a way to generate rounded images that were just images afterwards with no tricky css or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Another one is the [Thumbnailer](http://www.phpcontext.com/thumbnailer) class.