# HTML/CSS Best way rounded corners

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to create rounded corners using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css)

What is the best way to make rounded corners in div-containers! I need a solution which works in every browser .. what i have tried is

- jquery corner plugin (don't work in Chrome)
- CSS tags (don't work in IE)

Is the only working solution (for every browser) using images?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "best solution"? What are your criterias? There are tons of possible solutions with various drawbacks, some use javascript, some use lots of additional markup, some use lots of images. Please be more specific.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127227/css-rounded-corners & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823218/how-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css-or-javascript & http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rounded+corners

Answer (score 3):

If you need it to work everywhere and also account for possibility of JavaScript being turned off, then your only option is to use background images.

Answer (score 0):

I always thought that this solution was working in IE.. (haven't tested, no windows)

http://blog.benogle.com/2009/04/29/css-round-corners/

**EDIT:** Yes - it's at least working in IE 7.0

Comment: I can report that it works in Firefox 3.0 too, now how about you chrome and safari users...

Answer (score 0):

Which corner plugin are you using? Javascript rounded corners definitely work in Chrome. If you have a problem with a specific plugin ask for help specifically for that.

But in general for rounded corners, I prefer to use css. It looks nice for supported browsers, and degrades gracefully with no performance hits for IE (oftentimes looking just as nice, look, facebook just removed rounded corners: http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/08/26/facebook-tweaks-design-drops-rounded-corners/).

However if you must have rounded corners JS is a fine solution. Provide some examples of what's not working and we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Nifty Corners works like a charm. Crossbrowser compatible (Google reports that Chrome adapts the rounded corners beautifully as well).

http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html