# Rounded or sliced corners for Box Shapes in CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to have rounded corners or sliced corners for a box using CSS? If yes, please let me know the way.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, but please remove your email address.  SO members always post all answers so that everyone can benefit.

Comment: Please check out this SO question: [what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to have rounded corners:

```
.element {-webkit-border-radius: 1em; /* applies to all four corners */
          -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1em; /* applies to only the identified (top left) corner) */
          -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1em;
          -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
          -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;

          -moz-border-radius: 1em; /* applies to all four corners */
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 1em; /* applies only to identified (top left) corner */
          -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 1em /* and so on... */

          border-radius: 1em; /* CSS 3 only */
          border-top-right-radius: 1em; /* Applies to only identified (top right) corner */
}
```

I refer you to: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/border-radius/

Slashed corners, I think, would be doable only by using images.