# CSS Rounded Corner Divs

Tags: css, rounded-corners

How do I make only **one** or **two** or **three** corners of a div round?

Comment: Warning: none of the solutions so far offered works with IE <= 8.

Comment: I can't believe this is not a duplicate :)

Comment: oh yeah... it's actually not...

Comment: @egrunin Have you discovered a CSS corner rounding method that *does* work with versions of IE before 9?

Comment: @egrunin: IE's use slowly decreasing' still for solution you have to include "pie.htc" file to modify\upgrade the behavior of the browser... take a look at the following links as well they show some usage stats...

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

Comment: in cases when you have carefully thought about you target audience\users.... these stats can help you avoid a lot of complexity

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specify the corners you want:

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10% 5%;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: Alternatively for three rounded corners, round all the corners (`border-radius: 15px;`) and then turn rounding off on the corner you don't want it on (`border-top-left-radius: 0px;`).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a great resource that you can find helpful to do it for you and to learn.

http://borderradius.com/

Good luck!

Well to answer you question (apart from the tool):

One corner (top left):

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
```

Two corners (top left and right):

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

Three corners (top left and right and bottom right)

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
border-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
```

And so on...

All a 10px radius, very easily done with the tool I recommend.

BTW: Don't miss [idlefingers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431786/css-rounded-corner-divs/4431794#4431794)' answer, very good resource!!

See also: [Creating rounded corners using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css)

Comment: @joksnet I actually didn't know about it but it look great!! I'll give it a go!

Comment: Also check egrunin's answer that will give you options if you want to see other option that might be more compatible.

Answer (score 0):

**use of border-radius**

```
border-radius:5px;
```

further [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)

Answer (score -1):

None of the other answers work with IE8, so here's a link with *many* possible solutions:

[DevWebPro](http://devwebpro.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/)

Comment: @Akinator: i chose on First come first Serve basis... still A lotta lotta lotta thanks for the code...

Comment: @Junaid Saeed No problem! Glad to help and I think you made the right choice! :)

Comment: As far as I can see, all the solutions there are fundamentally different from corners rounded with CSS in that you need to create images to handle different radii, borders, background-colors, etc. The reason that rounding corners with CSS is great is that it frees you from lots of extra divs and graphics creation, which these solutions do not...