# How can I make div rounded corners with transparent background?

Tags: css, transparent, rounded-corners

How can I create a div with rounded corners and transparent backgrounds? A bit like twitter does. So that at the edge of the corners you can see the page background and not a black edge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to create rounded corners using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css)

Comment: @Daniel That question is specifically about using JavaScript, and the top answer is a jQuery library. This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @meagar Good call - I missed the tags - I thought the OP was looking for any way to do it. comment deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for a simple Radius, use this CSS:

```
div{
-moz-border-radius:10px;  /* for Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius:10px; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
border-radius:10px; /* regular */
opacity:0.5; /* Transparent Background 50% */
}
```

Greez, Chuggi

Comment: RGBA is what he's talking about, in reference to twitter. Opacity will make everything in the div transparent to 50%, RGBA will just fade what he wants.

Answer (score 9):

For full control over which elements are transparent and which are not, specify colors in rgba instead of hex:

```
div{
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background: #fff; /* fallback for browsers that don't understand rgba */
  border: solid 10px #000; /* fallback for browsers that don't understand rgba */
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); /* slighly transparent white */
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); /*Very transparent black*/
}
```

The fourth number within rgba is the level of transparency (alpha channel), 1 represents fully opaque and 0 is fully transparent.

Comment: Last attribute, 'border-color', is right? Or it should be only a rgba color like 'border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)?

Answer (score 1):

Using css3:

```
#divid {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: Removed my comment, I was thinking of something else.