# Make web user control background transparent

Tags: c#, asp.net, background, webusercontrol

Anyone who knows how to remove or make the background of a webuser control transparent or at least make the background corners same as my rounded border.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you get the round corners? Is it an image or is it done via css?

Comment: it is done in css: border-radius:4px;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make div rounded corners with transparent background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855348/how-can-i-make-div-rounded-corners-with-transparent-background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an image, convert to a .png file so you can cut out white parts and make it transparent.

If you're using a div, do what @cracker_chan says, `border-radius:4px;`