# tools for creating this menubar

Tags: css, menu, rounded-corners

Can you please tell me which tools do I need for creating this kind of round edged menu bars.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any tool you want : [Creating rounded corners using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css)