# Facebook likebox disappears in IExplore

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, html

My webpage works fine in iexplore when offline, and works fine in Firefox when online. But the whole page looks different in online IExplore, and I think this is caused by the facebook likebox.

I used css and html 5 only, with a little bit of javascript (onclick events), and the whole page is checked with expression web 4.

My webpage: www.hiddekat.nl

If someone knows the solution and would like to take a look for me, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue lies with your ajax call.

```
function IEXKUT () {if(some_object.attachEvent) {
window.alert('Helaas is Microsoft niet in staat om een stabiele browser te maken, voor optimaal resultaat adviseer ik Firefox, Google Chrome of Safari');
} else if(some_object.addEventListener) {
return false ();}
else {
return false ();
}}
```

Also, your not using the real likebox api: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box - just generate the likebox from this page and paste the code exactly how it is.

The other issues I have seen (not problematic, is that your rounded corners are images, perhaps look at this: [Creating rounded corners using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css) (pure CSS round boxes)