# How to make round corner box inside DIV tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, rounded-corners

I want to make round corner box inside div tag. How can I do that? Can you give me any example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to create rounded corners using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CSS:

```
.rounded-corners {
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Then add the class ".rounded-corners" to your div using jQuery:

```
$("#div-id").addClass("rounded-corners");
```

Comment: `border-radius` and `box-shadow` no longer require vendor prefixes. See: [MDN browser compatibility tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 5):

Use border-radius: 10px with CSS.

Also take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521432/best-jquery-rounded-corners-script

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the [`border-radius` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius). JavaScript has nothing to do with how elements look, just how they act.

```
<div style="border-radius:10px;height:100px;width:100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a safe way for a few browsers:

```
.box {
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use to `JQuery.Corner.Js` for make corner in div tag.

In first step add `jquery.corner.js` in to your page after 'jquery.js'

```
<script src="../JQuery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.corner.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Div1").corner();
        $("#Div2").corner("long");
    });     
</script>


<body>

    <div id="Div1" style="background-color: blue; 
        width: 150px; height: 150px;">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="Div2" style="background-color: blue; 
        width: 150px; height: 150px;">
    </div>
    <br />
</body>
```

You can find more sample in this address [JQuery Corner Demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/)