# css transparent rounded corners separator

Tags: javascript, html, json, css

I have CSS issue , how i do achieve css rounded corner's as separators thanks. the selected is transparent.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating rounded corners using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/creating-rounded-corners-using-css)

Comment: Be much more specific about your query.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly you mean these 'negative' corners on the grey area?

You could try to play with pseudoelements (`:after`, `:before`).

Something like:

```
li {
    position: relative;
}
li:after {
    background-color: white;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: HI, where i have the text , is a selected item  ... so basically the selected item should have the border-radius @ the bottom

Answer (score -1):

Where your css selector is try the following:

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

This tells the browser to make the borders rounded based on a pixel count you give it. Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) (W3Schools).