# how to create bottom cruved outside and top croved to inside of div's in css

Tags: html, css

I am looking for the best way to create two sides curved container in CSS.
the bottom of the first div need to be curved outside, and the next div needs to be curved inside.

Here is a picture of the design:

[image: picture of the design]

the first div curved can be done by `border-radius` maybe, but what about the other one?
also a note, this should be a responsive design.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try anything? Show us some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating rounded corners using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/creating-rounded-corners-using-css)

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`SVG` is a better option. If you still want to do it using CSS then see this: [S curve using css](https://jsfiddle.net/z62jf1so/)

Comment: You can also use transparent png image as background

Comment: I think it can also be created using CSS `border-radius` by rounding only certain sides of the element a certain amount. Nonetheless I agree that SVG is a better solution

Comment: Another example: https://codepen.io/jbutler483/pen/NqRqgG